# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Cart\App' not found

Tags: php, slim, shopping-cart

I was following codesource's [Build a shopping cart](https://www.codecourse.com/lessons/build-a-shopping-cart/) then i get the error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Cart\App' not found in G:\PleskVhosts\tohokiwatch.com\httpdocs\cart\bootstrap\app.php on line 9

I am using GoDaddy to host my web and here are my codes:

app.php:

```html
<?php

use Cart\App;

session_start();

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new App;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/routes.php';

?>
```

App.php:

```html
<?php

namespace Cart;

use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use DI\Bridge\Slim\App as DiBridge;

class App extends DIBridge
{
 protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $builder)
 {
  $builder->addDefinitions([
   'settings.displayErrorDetails' => true,
  ]);
 }
}

?>
```

index.php:

```html
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';

$app->run();

?>
```

composer.json:

```html
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.0",
        "slim/twig-view": "^2.3",
        "php-di/slim-bridge": "^1.0",
        "illuminate/database": "^5.5"
    },
 "autoload":{
  "psr-4":{
   "cart\\":"app"
  }
 }
}
```

My GoDaddy file directory:
[File Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BnCH.png)

Comment: You should first require `vendor/autoload.php` and then `use Cart\App`. Try to swap lines with `use Cart\App;` and `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: still couldn't solve it...

Comment: ok i got it..... in the composer.json i should put "Cart\\" instead of "cart\\"